# Replace spaces with underscore only in tag

Tags: php, xml, preg-replace

data:  `<product name_here>Product A</product_name here>`

I try this `$replace = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $replace);`

but it show incorrect like this : `<product_name_here>Product_A</product_name_here>`

Just only replace space with underscore only inside tag name , no need to change space in value

I want like this :  `<product_name_here>Product A</product_name_here>`

Please help.

Comment: ... actually, you're attempting to clean a duff XML feed? This could be tricky with `regexps` since there may be attributes on those nodes; e.g. `<product_name_here product_meta_title="Here is some random attribute with spaces in that need to be preserved"> ... </product_name_here>`

Comment: @CD001: could you show us how to solve this specific example when the opening and closing tag don't have the same name with DOMDocument ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte not without more clarification on the question I don't think. Are the tags really called `product_name_here` (or some variant thereof) or are they being populated from a database with actual product names? Is it possible for the tags to have attributes? Honestly, I'd look at what's generating the XML in the first place rather than attempting to "sticky plaster" it after the fact... and not with DOMDocument (though I would build the file initially with it); I'd totally changed my previous comment before you posted yours (after re-reading the question) :P

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
$before = '<product name_here>Product A</product_name here>';
$after = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*)\s+([^<]*>)/', '$1_$2', $before);
echo $after;
```

This should give

```
<product_name_here>Product A</product_name_here>
```

The parts before and after \s+ specify that you don't want the spaces outside of a tag pairing but just the ones who are enclosed between an opening tag `<` and a closing tag `>`.
The `$1` and `$2` substitute back in the strings before and after the replaced whitespace.

Comment: I've a feeling this may be a little specific and that `product_name_here` is simply a placeholder for an XML feed holding actual product names as tag names... `<geoffreys marvellous badger tickler>` for instance wouldn't work on this. I could, of course, be utterly wrong in this suspicion.

Comment: @CD001 You are probably right. But perhaps  `<geoffreys_marvellous_badger_tickler>` is the wanted result. Then it would work.
It would not work on attributes like you stated before.

Comment: Thank you Daniel82 this is work for me, but I got another problem

I found some value have whitespace 

like this   

<product_name_here>P roduct A</product_name_here>
 or 
<product_name_here>Pro duct A</product_name_here> 

How can I fix it to 

<product_name_here>Product A</product_name_here>


Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a way without knowing a list of valid values. How would you know if a whitespace is correct or not. I think you should listen to @CD001 and try to fix whatever is causing the corrupted XML. Fix it at the source if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a better example?

In my understanding you want this:

You have: Product A

You want: Product A

Is that correct?

If that's the case all you need to do is str_replace(' ','_',$product)

Sorry for my bad english.